# Display mdbootstrap cascading cards inline

Tags: reactjs, jsx, mdbootstrap

Hello everyone,

I am building a website using react js. Now I want to display three mdbootstrap cascading cards inline using react js.

Here a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVh9e.jpg)

Belove the code: (please note that on this page there is a navbar, video carousel, the cascading cards and a footer).

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, CarouselIndicator, Row, Col, CardTitle, CardText, CardBody, CardImage, Button, Card, CarouselIndicators, Carousel, CarouselControl, CarouselInner, CarouselItem } from 'mdbreact';

export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.next = this.next.bind(this);
    this.prev = this.prev.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      activeItem: 1,
      maxLength: 3
    };
  }

  next() {
    const nextItem = this.state.activeItem + 1;
    if(nextItem > this.state.maxLength) {
      this.setState({ activeItem: 1 });
    } else {
      this.setState({ activeItem: nextItem });
    }
  }

  prev() {
    const prevItem = this.state.activeItem - 1;
    if(prevItem < 1) {
      this.setState({ activeItem: this.state.maxLength });
    } else {
      this.setState({ activeItem: prevItem });
    }
  }

  goToIndex(item) {
    if (this.state.activeItem !== item) {
      this.setState({
        activeItem: item
      });
    }
  }

  render(){
    const { activeItem } = this.state;
    return(
        <div>
            <Carousel 
              activeItem={this.state.activeItem}
              next={this.next}
              className="z-depth-1">
              <CarouselInner>
                <CarouselItem itemId="1">
                  <video className="video-fluid d-block" autoPlay loop>
                    <source src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/video/Tropical.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                  </video>
                </CarouselItem>
                <CarouselItem itemId="2">
                  <video className="video-fluid d-block" autoPlay loop>
                    <source src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/video/forest.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                  </video>
                </CarouselItem>
                <CarouselItem itemId="3">
                  <video className="video-fluid d-block" autoPlay loop>
                    <source src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/video/Agua-natural.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                  </video>
                </CarouselItem>
              </CarouselInner>
              <CarouselControl direction="prev" role="button" onClick={() => { this.prev(); }} />
              <CarouselControl direction="next" role="button" onClick={() => { this.next(); }} />
            </Carousel>
            <Container>
        <h4 className="mt-5 mb-2">Multi-item Carousel</h4>
        <Carousel 
          multiItem
          activeItem={this.state.activeItem}
          next={this.next}>
          <div className="controls-top">
            <CarouselControl iconLeft className="btn-floating" direction="prev" role="button" onClick={() => { this.prev(); }} />
            <CarouselControl iconRight className="btn-floating" direction="next" role="button" onClick={() => { this.next(); }} />
          </div>
          <CarouselIndicators>
            <CarouselIndicator active={activeItem === 1 ? true : false} onClick={() => { this.goToIndex(1); }}></CarouselIndicator>
            <CarouselIndicator active={activeItem === 2 ? true : false} onClick={() => { this.goToIndex(2); }}></CarouselIndicator>
            <CarouselIndicator active={activeItem === 3 ? true : false} onClick={() => { this.goToIndex(3); }}></CarouselIndicator>
          </CarouselIndicators>
          <CarouselInner>
            <Row>
              <CarouselItem itemId="1">
                <Col md="4">
                  <Card className="mb-2">
                  <CardImage className="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(34).jpg" />
                    <CardBody>
                      <CardTitle>Card title</CardTitle>
                      <CardText>Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</CardText>
                      <Button color="primary">Button</Button>
                    </CardBody>
                  </Card>
                </Col>
                <Col md="4" className="clearfix d-none d-md-block">
                  <Card className="mb-2">
                  <CardImage className="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(18).jpg" />
                    <CardBody>
                      <CardTitle>Card title</CardTitle>
                      <CardText>Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</CardText>
                      <Button color="primary">Button</Button>
                    </CardBody>
                  </Card>
                </Col>
                <Col md="4" className="clearfix d-none d-md-block">
                  <Card className="mb-2">
                  <CardImage className="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(35).jpg" />
                    <CardBody>
                      <CardTitle>Card title</CardTitle>
                      <CardText>Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</CardText>
                      <Button color="primary">Button</Button>
                    </CardBody>
                  </Card>
                </Col>
              </CarouselItem>
              <CarouselItem itemId="2">
                <Col md="4">
                  <Card className="mb-2">
                  <CardImage className="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(60).jpg" />
                    <CardBody>
                      <CardTitle>Card title</CardTitle>
                      <CardText>Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</CardText>
                      <Button color="primary">Button</Button>
                    </CardBody>
                  </Card>
                </Col>
                <Col md="4" className="clearfix d-none d-md-block">
                  <Card className="mb-2">
                  <CardImage className="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(47).jpg" />
                    <CardBody>
                      <CardTitle>Card title</CardTitle>
                      <CardText>Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</CardText>
                      <Button color="primary">Button</Button>
                    </CardBody>
                  </Card>
                </Col>
                <Col md="4" className="clearfix d-none d-md-block">
                  <Card className="mb-2">
                  <CardImage className="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(48).jpg" />
                    <CardBody>
                      <CardTitle>Card title</CardTitle>
                      <CardText>Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</CardText>
                      <Button color="primary">Button</Button>
                    </CardBody>
                  </Card>
                </Col>
              </CarouselItem>
              <CarouselItem itemId="3">
                <Col md="4">
                  <Card className="mb-2">
                  <CardImage className="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(53).jpg" />
                    <CardBody>
                      <CardTitle>Card title</CardTitle>
                      <CardText>Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</CardText>
                      <Button color="primary">Button</Button>
                    </CardBody>
                  </Card>
                </Col>
                <Col md="4" className="clearfix d-none d-md-block">
                  <Card className="mb-2">
                  <CardImage className="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(45).jpg" />
                    <CardBody>
                      <CardTitle>Card title</CardTitle>
                      <CardText>Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</CardText>
                      <Button color="primary">Button</Button>
                    </CardBody>
                  </Card>
                </Col>
                <Col md="4" className="clearfix d-none d-md-block">
                  <Card className="mb-2">
                  <CardImage className="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(41).jpg" />
                    <CardBody>
                      <CardTitle>Card title</CardTitle>
                      <CardText>Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</CardText>
                      <Button color="primary">Button</Button>
                    </CardBody>
                  </Card>
                </Col>
              </CarouselItem>
            </Row>
          </CarouselInner>
        </Carousel>
      </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Could someone please help me?

Thanks,

Nico

Answer (score 0):

In my case, carousel with multiple item is one of feature for pro version. But, i tried to solve this case with free version, and found that Row and Col components are not working for this case.

So, I've removed it and wrapped cards components inside CarouselItem with

```
<div style={{flexDirection: "row"}}> ... </div>
```

I hope this can be helpful.